# How can I style a wrapper View without targeting the children?

Tags: react-native

Sorry I know this probably is a stupid question but I'm new to React Native and I can't seem to find a solution to this looking it up. Thank you in advance for your help.

I'm trying to give the HeadingWrapper a box-shadow but it seems to give the shadow to the inner contents. Here is my code that produces [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XrGY.png) result:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import H1 from "../common/headings";
import LeftArrow from "../assets/LeftArrow.png";

const MainWrapper = styled.View`
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000000;

`;

const HeadingWrapper = styled.View`
  padding: 60px 10px 0 10px;
  height: 60px;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
`;

const ScrollArea = styled.ScrollView`

`;

const Img = styled.Image`

`;

class LandingPage extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <MainWrapper style={styles.mainWrapper}>
                <HeadingWrapper>
                    <Img style={styles.leftArrow} source={LeftArrow}/>
                    <H1>Chats</H1>
                </HeadingWrapper>
                <ScrollArea>

                </ScrollArea>
            </MainWrapper>
        );
    }
}
```

headings.js:

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';
import React from "react";


const InnerH1 = styled.Text`
  font-size: 34px;
  font-weight: bold;
`;

const H1Container = styled.View`
  flex: 1;
`;

const H1 = (props) => {
    return (
        <H1Container>
            <InnerH1>{props.children}</InnerH1>
        </H1Container>
    )
};


export default H1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the background color of `HeadingWrapper` is transparent as no background color is currently specified.

To create the 'box-shadow', all you need to do is give `HeadingWrapper` a background color of which is the same as your background.

Per the screenshot provided, the background color is white. Thus, you can use white as the background color for `HeadingWrapper`.

For inline style, you can use the below code:

```
<HeadingWrapper style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
    <Img style={styles.leftArrow} source={LeftArrow}/>
    <H1>Chats</H1>
</HeadingWrapper>
```